# iPhone "addSubView" method and view initialization

Tags: iphone, initialization, addsubview

I want to show a new view on the screen. Before showing it, I want to initialize it with an image that was just capture by the camera.
This is a part of the code:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.photoPreviewView.view];    
UIImageView *photo = self.photoPreviewView.imageView;
[[self captureManager] captureStillImage:photo];
```

As you can notice, I first call the addSubView and only later setting the photo. I do it since the "imageView" (of "photoPreviewView.imageView") is only accessible after calling "addSubView".

This creates a not nice experience, when first the view is shown in white, and only then a photo is being shown.

Is there a way of handling this issue?

Comment: you can make image view as transparent, self.photoPreviewView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; or may be put some default image until new image is loaded...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your question but,
you can try this before your code :

```
[self.photoPreviewView.view addSubview:nil];
```

Maybe it will allow you to access to `imageView` property of `photoPreviewView`.

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Your suggestion does work. I can access the "imageView" member of "photoPreviewView". But, the problem, for some reason, remains: The camera takes the picture, then I see a white screen for a second, only then I see the photo on the new view. I expected that since I assigned the image to the view before adding the subView, the image should already be there. Any solution for that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not really enough information - if photoPreviewView is created by loading
from a NIB file and imageView is an IBOutlet then the linkages are not
established for the imageView until after you have accessed the view attribute of photoPreviewView.

If this is the case simply do a

```
[self.photoPreviewView view];
[[self.captureManager captureStillImage:self.photoPreviewView.imageView];
[self.view add subView;self.photoPreviewView.view];
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is good, but I still have the problem. You can look at the note I wrote on the next answer.